How to define a Vector with only integers ≥ 0
As input for a function, I need a Vector with values greater than or equal to zero.
I tried l = Array{>:Unsigned, 1} because Unsigned is subtype of Integer.
However push!(l, 9) throws an error.
MethodError: no method matching push!(::Type{Vector{>:Unsigned}}, ::Int64)
What is the right way to define such an array?
Use case:
function concat_ints(l::Array{Int64, 1})::Int64
    """
    concat_ints([3, 4, 5]) == 345
    """
    @assert all(n -> n ∈ 0:9, l) "Only digits in range 0:9 are allowed inputs"
    s = 0 # sum
    for (i, n) in enumerate(reverse(l))
        s += n * 10^(i-1)
    end
    return s
end

I would like to replace the @assert all(n -> n ∈ 0:9, l) part by enforcing the right input type.

The type you are looking for is probably Array{<:Unsigned, 1}, not Array{>:Unsigned, 1}. But also, l = Array{>:Unsigned, 1} doesn't create a vector of unsigned numbers, it creates a type variable.
It's like writing t = Int32. That doesn't make t a Int32, it makes t a type variable. Observe:
julia> t = Int32
Int32

julia> typeof(t)
DataType

julia> t = Int32(0)
0

julia> typeof(t)
Int32

So what you probably want is l = Vector{UInt}(). Now, only positive values can be pushed into the vector:
julia> push!(l, 9)
1-element Vector{UInt64}:
 0x0000000000000009

julia> push!(l, -9)
ERROR: InexactError: convert(UInt64, -9)

BTW: Using a container like l = Vector{<:Unsigned}() won't work either, since it cannot be instantiated. You could write l = Vector{Unsigned}(), but I wouldn't recommend it, since that would be bad for performance, since the vector has to be able to handle all different sort of unsigned types. Instead, choose a concrete unsigned type like UInt64, UInt32 or so on.

First, I would suggest evaluating why you want to do this logic with typing alone. It does not seem to have any obvious benefits- a single line of logic would seem to be similarly functional while being more readable. This looks, at a glance, like an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . That being said, assuming isn't usually helpful, and it is totally possible to do so with typing.
The "Unsigned" version of Integer types, UInt, are restricted to non-negative numbers. So, as long as you are don't need floating point numbers, restricting elements of a Vector to UInt will result in your expected behavior.
# Let's create an empty Vector restricted to UInts
julia> myVec = Vector{UInt}()
UInt64[]

# Let's push 0 to to
julia> push!(myVec,0)
1-element Vector{UInt64}:
 0x0000000000000000

# Let's push 1 to it
julia> push!(myVec,1)
2-element Vector{UInt64}:
 0x0000000000000000
 0x0000000000000001

# Now Let's try pushing a negative number to it
julia> push!(myVec,-1)
ERROR: InexactError: check_top_bit(UInt64, -1)
...
# It errors when trying to push a negative number!
# ... which is expected, and what you wanted.

Now let's implement it into your function. Note that since we have restricted the input typing for the function, we now need to make sure that the input is of the right type (so [3,4,5] will no longer be accepted)!
# Let's create the function with the new function
julia> function concat_ints(l::Vector{UInt})::Int64
    println("Getting Concatted Ints!") # debug statement
    s = 0 # sum
    for (i, n) in enumerate(reverse(l))
        s += n * 10^(i-1)
    end
    return s
end

concat_ints (generic function with 1 method)

julia> myVec = UInt.([3,4,5])
3-element Vector{UInt64}:
 0x0000000000000003
 0x0000000000000004
 0x0000000000000005

julia> concat_ints(myVec)
Getting Concatted Ints!
345

This all works, but it may be unwanted that inputs need to be defined with UInt.(someVectorGoesHere). While this is the necessary drawback from the approach we are taking, we could also make it a little more redundant by creating a second, more general, dispatch of the concat_ints function.
# Let's create a second version for when the vector isn't UInts 
julia> function concat_ints(l::Vector{Int})
    println("Those Werent Not UInts...")
    try
        concat_ints(UInt.(l))
    catch
        println("They were negative! Grrr")
    end
end

concat_ints (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> concat_ints(UInt.([3,4,5]))
Getting Concatted Ints!
345

julia> concat_ints([3,4,5])
Those Werent Not UInts...
Getting Concatted Ints!
345

julia> concat_ints([-3,4,5])
Those Werent Not UInts...
They were negative! Grrr

Since try-catch flows are relatively slow, it would still be recommended to use UInt.(someVector) to define your inputs, even with the redundancy we built in. Hope this helps!
